# What happens when SET NAMES does not match a table's character set?

Tags: mysql, iso-8859-1, utf8mb4

I have a database with tables set as `CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4`, however I've discovered that the mysql connection (`SET NAMES`) has been `latin1`.

My questions are:

1. What happens to that data? Has MySQL been converting it to `utf8mb4` to store it, or has it stored the data as `latin1`?
2. If I need to convert it, should I connect as `SET NAMES latin1` to take the data out, convert it, and put it back in, or connect as `utf8mb4` to pull the data out?

Answer (score 3):

Data is stored in the character set defined in the table, so in your case all the data will be stored in `utf8mb4`.

Every connection to the database uses a character set for sending and receiving data. That character set might be different, so mysql converts between the storage character set and the connection character set.

So, to answer your questions:

1) mysql converts it.

2) you don't need to convert it. But you need to make sure that if you use `set names`, you actually are sending data using the character set you claim.

More here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html

Comment: Well stated.  This is a common issue with noobies.